# Joomla 3.0—get module id inside custom form

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-module

I have created Joomla module and added a custom field type at the parameter configuration in the backend, using the .xml file like this:

```
<fields name="params">
    <fieldset
        addfieldpath="/modules/<module_name>/fields" name="basic">
            <field  name="articles" type="articles" label="label" />

.
.
.
</fields>
```

That is working pretty fine but there is on question left over: How can I access the **module's id** inside the custom field class, when invoked to create the fields html?

Thanks in ahead!

**UPDATE**

I digged a bit deeper in that found the `JModuleHelper::getModule($type, $name)` method, which returns either the first module of the given `$type` if no `$name` is specified, or the module of the given `$type` having the `$name`, **but** since it is possible to create Modules with the same name, this approach is kind of ugly.

Comment: $app = JFactory::getApplication();
$module_id = $app->input->getInt('id');

Answer (score 1):

The solution is hidden in the URL and in case of Joomla, in `JInput`. Complete and more verbose explanation is [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=715&t=832669&p=3130867#p3130867) (a the bottom), but in short:

URL of a modules edit screen:

```
index.php?option=com_modules&view=module&layout=edit&id=87
```

Would be too easy to just use this…